# Circular Dependency in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm trying to use restTemplate in my bootspring project, when i compile giving me error like this:

```
There is a circular dependency between 4 beans in the application context:
- courseController (field com.example.service.CourseService com.example.controller.CourseController.courseDAO)
- courseServiceRest (field private com.example.dao.CourseDAO com.example.service.CourseServiceRest.courseDAO)
- courseDAOImpl (field private org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.example.dao.CourseDAOImpl.restTemplate)
- studentDAOImpl (field private org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate com.example.dao.StudentDAOImpl.restTemplate)
- restTemplate
```

Here is my code below:

I think because i have same @bean in StudenDAOImpl and CourseDAOImpl, because if i delete CourseDAOImpl compile success, the code is below:

StudentDAOImpl code:

```
@Service
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
       return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public StudentModel selectStudent (String npm)
    {
        StudentModel student = restTemplate.getForObject(url+npm, StudentModel.class);
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public List<StudentModel> selectAllStudents ()
    {
       return null;
    }

}
```

CourseDAOImpl code:

```
@Service
public class CourseDAOImpl implements CourseDAO {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    public CourseModel selectCourse(String id) {
        CourseModel course = restTemplate.getForObject(urlCourse+id, CourseModel.class);
        return course;
    }

    @Override
    public List<CourseModel> selectAllCourses() {   
        return null;    
    }
}
```

Any answer? Thank you very much.

Comment: Remove all the `@Bean` methods and put a single `@Bean` method in 1 of your configuration files.

Comment: Can you give me example, i don't have any configuration files i guess

Comment: Yes you do. You have a class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` which is a `@Configuration` class. Just add it to that.

Comment: It success, after compile but in my browser shows only loading screen tab not the result on my view.

Comment: Then you probably have another issue unrelated to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your DAOs you should remove the `@Bean` configuration and have it look like this following for each DAO

```
@Service
public class StudentDAOImpl implements StudentDAO
{
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    public StudentModel selectStudent (String npm)
    {
        StudentModel student = restTemplate.getForObject(url+npm, StudentModel.class);
        return student;
    }

    @Override
    public List<StudentModel> selectAllStudents ()
    {
       return null;
    }

}
```

Then in a configuration Bean or in your entry point application you can add your restTemplate bean. For example here is a configuration Bean in Config.java

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
     @Bean
     public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
       return builder.build();
     }
}
```

Comment: and which folder i need to put Config.java? i put CourseDAOImpl and StudentDAOImpl in DAO Folder

Comment: I mean how to include that Config.java into my StudentDAOImpl?

Comment: I like to make a package for Configs so I have a folder called AppConfiguration and put my configs there

Comment: Spring will automatically know how to use it because it'll be picked up by the Spring Auto Configuration annotation.

Comment: you want to give an error? It's not helpful to just say `not working`.

Comment: I'm really sorry here's:  This page isn’t working, localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in my browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143032/discussion-between-mike-tung-and-andhika).